# How to add last two digits of year to hibernate search / lucene index

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

In my database I store years in it's complete form. Example, `2012,2013,2014` etc. This is also how they are being stored in my index. I'm looking to also store the last two digits in the index as well. Example `12,13,14` etc. I basically want to enable individuals to be able to do a keyword search on 2012 and 12.

My main search analyzer looks like this.

```
@AnalyzerDefs({
    @AnalyzerDef(name = "searchtokenanalyzer",
            // Split input into tokens according to tokenizer
            tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
            filters = {
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
                    @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "([^a-zA-Z0-9\\-])"),
                    @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = ""),
                    @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")}),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = TrimFilterFactory.class)
            }),
```

I have  a second analyzer for handling the year abbreviation that looks like this.

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "yearanalyzer",
            // Split input into tokens according to tokenizer
            // Split input into tokens according to tokenizer
            tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
            filters = {
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
                    @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "^.{2}"),
                    @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = ""),
                    @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")}),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = TrimFilterFactory.class)
            })
```

And on my entity field I have the following.

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class YearLookup 
    @Fields({
            @Field(name = "name", store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES,
                    analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "searchtokenanalyzer")),
            @Field(name = "abbr", store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, 
                    analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "yearanalyzer"))
        })
        private String name;
    }
```

Now so far everything is making in the index correctly, I can see

```
name 2012,2013,2014
abbr 12,13,14
```

Now when I do a search against against YearLookup.class with the following code. The abbr year gets cut down by two digits again creating a null value while name remains in tact.

```
public interface SearchParam {
    public static final String[] SEARCH_FIELDS = new String[]{"yearLookup.name", "yearLookup.abbr"};
}

String searchString = "14";

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(YearLookup.class).get();

ermMatchingContext onWildCardFields = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField(SearchParam.SEARCH_FIELDS[0]);
            TermMatchingContext onFuzzyFields = queryBuilder.keyword().fuzzy().withThreshold(0.7f)
                    .withPrefixLength(1).onField(SearchParam.SEARCH_FIELDS[0]);

            //Iterate over all the remaining search fields stored in the "VehicleListing" index 
            for (int i = 1; i < SearchParam.SEARCH_FIELDS.length; i++) {
                onWildCardFields.andField(SearchParam.SEARCH_FIELDS[i]);
                onFuzzyFields.andField(SearchParam.SEARCH_FIELDS[i]);
            }

            String[] tokens = searchString.toLowerCase().split("\\s");

            for (String token : tokens) {
                luceneQuery = queryBuilder.bool()
                        .should(onWildCardFields.matching(token + "*").createQuery())
                        .should(onFuzzyFields.matching(token).createQuery())
                        .createQuery();
            }

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, YearLookup.class);

Integer results = fullTextQuery.getResultSize();
```

Now when I run my test case against this. I get the following exception.

HSEARCH000146: The query string '14' applied on field 'yearLookup.abbr' has no meaningfull tokens to be matched. Validate the query input against the Analyzer applied on this field.
org.hibernate.search.errors.EmptyQueryException
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.createQuery(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.createQuery(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:86)
    at com.domain.auto.services.search.impl.SearchManagerImpl.doSearch(SearchManagerImpl.java:146)
    at $SearchManager_138fdc525111b303.doSearch(Unknown Source)
    at $SearchManager_138fdc525111b2f3.doSearch(Unknown Source)
    at com.domain.auto.services.search.impl.SearchServiceImplTest.testYearSearch(SearchServiceImplTest.java:92)

Anybody have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "yearanalyzer",
        // Split input into tokens according to tokenizer
        // Split input into tokens according to tokenizer
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
                @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "^\\d{2}(\\d{2})$"),
                @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = "$1"),
                @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")}),
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bridge and handle String for both case as below:

```
 @FieldBridge(impl = YearFieldBridge.class)
 private String name;
```

And create bridge class some how similer to this:

```
public class YearFieldBridge implements StringBridge, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object value) {
        if(value != null) {
            if(value instanceof String) {
                String strVal = (String) value;
                strVal = strVal.toUpperCase();
                if(strVal.length() == 2){
                    return "20"+strVal;
                }else{
                    return strVal;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```